# Angular2 - switch between styles

Tags: css, typescript, angular

I'm currently working on an application using Angular2. 
Now that I finished my styling of the app, I want to make more themes to switch between.

I've tried setting my styleUrls to a variable and change it on click, but this doesn't work.

```
    let styles= nightflat

@Component({
      selector: 'start-app',
      template: `
<div class="ui-g ui-g-nopad">
      <div class="ui-g-12 ui-g-nopad" id="header">
            <img src="../src/resources/icon/c2logo.png" alt="Logo" id="logo">
            <button pButton icon="fa-sign-out" id="LogOut" type="button" label="LogOut" (click)="gotoLogout()"></button>
            <h1></h1> 
      </div>
      <div class="ui-g-12 ui-g-nopad">
            <p-breadcrumb [model]="bcitems"></p-breadcrumb>
      </div>
      <div class="ui-g-12 ui-g-nopad"> 
            <div class="ui-g-2 ui-g-nopad"> 
                  <p-panelMenu id="menu" [model]="itempanel"></p-panelMenu>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-g-10 ui-g-nopad" id="router-outlet">
                  <router-outlet> </router-outlet>
                  <div class="ui-g-12 ui-g-nopad">
                  <button pButton id="goBack" type="button" label="Zurück" (click)="goBack()"></button>
            </div>
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
    `
      ,
      styleUrls: [styles],
      directives: [Button],
      providers: []
})
```

"nightflat" is an import from my style-urls.ts providing a css-path for every style I want to use (til now only 2):

```
export var nightflat = './dist/resources/scss/app.component.css'
export var froggy = './dist/resources/scss/test.component.css'
```

I then tried to use a function called by a Buttonclickevent to set the styles variable to another value.

```
setStyle(){
styles = froggy;
}
```

Well, that doesn't work at all. 
First question: As I'm using gulp-inject - do I have to inject ALL of the style-sheets into my index.html? 
Second question: How am I supposed to switch theming onclick?

Comment: You could base your styling on a class of your body tag like `<body class="nightflat">`

Comment: And how can I switch between froggy/nightflat then? Sorry, I'm inexperienced. Is there away to change the injected css paths?

Comment: If you want to change it during runtime, you could use `$('body').removeClass('nightflat'); $('body').addClass('froggy');`

Comment: Ah, I got this. But I actually want to try it in another way. Is there a possibility in Angular2 to access the <link href="*.css"> and change the href value?